# What does the Delete key do on the English QWERTY keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

I have a French AZERTY keyboard with a Backspace key (that can be modified with Fn into Delete) and to my surprise I saw on the Apple Store that the English QWERTY keyboard had a Delete key in its place, so I'm wondering if it's really a Delete key (erase right) that can be modified with Fn into Backspace, or not.
Edit: If I try on the virtual keyboard with American layout, the key does erase left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the English QWERTY keyboards, the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key functions as a <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key, and can be turned into an erase right key with the <kbd>fn</kbd> modified key.

Comment: Then I must ask: why is it labelled Delete ?

Comment: I actually don't know; maybe ask it as a question here. ;)

Comment: I can see that it wouldn't be labelled Backspace because thanks to the modifier key it can erase both ways. But I don't see why the label is different on AZERTY when the behaviour is the same.

Answer (score 1):

The <kbd>Delete</kbd> (delete forward) key, when standalone, is called <kbd>Del</kbd> on both Mac and PC keyboards.  Of the 6 keyboards I have convenient here (1 each full size and laptop PC, 2 full-size and 2 laptop Mac), the delete-backwards key is called <kbd>Backspace</kbd> on the PC keyboards and <kbd>Delete</kbd> on the Macs.  (The <kbd>Del</kbd> key is called that on all the keyboards that have it or a marker for it.)

Pedantically, the Macs are correct, as the concept of "backspace" doesn't include erasing but the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> / <kbd>Delete</kbd> key does erase.